# Inline, Unordered List Item Height 100%

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I am building an inline, unordered list that in my application. The first item in this list should have its text vertically aligned to the top of the list, then should display a vertical line to its right that stretches to 100% height of the parent `<ul>` element, like so, where 1 is the first list item, and 2 represents the second:

```
1 | 2
  | 2
  | 2
  | 2
```

Here is a watered down example of my code, which does not display like the example above: http://jsfiddle.net/spryno724/hSpvr/1/. Could someone please adjust the CSS so that the line stretches to 100% height?

I would like to avoid using a specific height, such as `120px`, since the height of the other lists items may vary.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the property `display: table-cell;` instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/sg3s/hSpvr/6/

No support in IE7 though. ( http://caniuse.com/#search=table-cell )

If you need a different way, I don't think there is one (not anything that gracefull anyway).

As a side note, the pseudo selector `:first-child` works in IE7+ so you don't need that `first` class.

Comment: That totally worked! I'm not focusing on support for IE7, so this is fabulous!

Comment: ... and thanks. I've gotten used to ignoring any "fancy CSS" just because of IE. |-( I'll use `:first-child` instead.

Comment: It is a common problem; read this article: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201002/forgotten_css_selectors/

Answer (score 0):

You need to either employ absolute positioning on the first item, or just use a border-left on the second. A rule like 'height: 100%' won't work unless the ul has an explicit width.